# getting java library error in application

Tags: java, websphere

I have a web application that is deployed on WebSphere and that use one java library to generate files in excel format but I am getting the following error in WebSphere, but it will work fine with the TOMCAT server.

What can the problem be?

ERROR IS :-

> Error 500: java.lang.LinkageError: LinkageError while defining class:
>
> jxl.format.CellFormat Could not be defined due to: (jxl/format/CellFormat) bad major version at offset=6 This is often caused by having a class defined at multiple locations within the classloader hierarchy. Other potential causes include compiling against an older or newer version of the class that has an incompatible method signature. Dumping the current context classloader hierarchy: ==> indicates defining classloader ==>[0] com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@50c450c4 Local ClassPath: C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\axis.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\cglib-nodep-2.2.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-discovery-0.2.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-net-2.0.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\iText-5.0.6.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\jaxrpc.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\jdom-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\jettison-1.0.1.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\joda-time-1.6.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\json-rpc-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\jxl.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\mail-1.4.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\ojdbc14.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\quartz-all-1.5.2.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\saaj.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\scheduler-plugin-example.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\scheduler-plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\sqljdbc.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\stax-1.2.0.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\wsdl4j.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\xml-writer-0.2.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\xom-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\xstream-1.3.1.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war\WEB-INF\lib\xstream-benchmark-1.3.1.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\yagneshNode01Cell\apptoolv2.ear\apptoolv2.war Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST [1] com.ibm.ws.classloader.JarClassLoader@738995212 Local Classpath: Delegation mode: PARENT_FIRST [2] com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader@60e060e0 [3] com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader@70567056 [4] org.eclipse.osgi.framework.adaptor.core.CDSBundleClassLoader@4e024e02 [5] sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6b806b80 [6] sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@3fe03fe ---Original exception--- java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (jxl/format/CellFormat) bad major version at offset=6 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:222) at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:148) at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:526) at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.findClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:477) at .............

Comment: Did you read the first few lines in the error message? *This is often caused by having a class defined at multiple locations within the classloader hierarchy. Other potential causes include compiling against an older or newer version of the class that has an incompatible method signature.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
Could not be defined due to: (jxl/format/CellFormat) bad major version at offset=6
```

You're using a JExcel library compiled for a version of Java that your application server does not support.  You'll either need to recompile the library or move to a newer version of WebSphere Application Server.

(The product printed the same "defined at multiple locations" error with class loader dump for all LinkageError, regardless of whether that text is actually relevant, until around 6.1.0.21.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got Andy Khan's JExcel library in the CLASSPATH twice.  See if WebSphere ships with it.  If it does, remove yours from the application WEB-INF/lib and see if that helps.

Comment: you right i am using andy khan's jxl.jar..but what the solution of this problem....

Comment: WebSphere doesn't ship with jxl.jar.

Comment: But it is possible you've got jxl.jar in multiple places. Maybe you copied jxl.jar somewhere else in addition to your WEB-INF/lib? See the JSP at [this blog post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/Dougclectica/entry/revive_finding_a_java_class_in_your_servlet_container2) to try to locate which jar is providing any particular class.